# Is mmap working with SPI device?

Tags: linux, mmap, spi

I want to use SPI interface to read and write the registers in an external FPGA (so I called it SPI device). I know Linux kernel has the spi driver. So can I use mmap? If yes, should I open the device file through "/sys/bus/spi/devices/DEVICE_NAME" in my code?

I noticed that when I cd to "/sys/bus/spi/devices/SPI_DEVICE_NAME", the path was changed automatically to "/sys/devices/soc.0/CORE_NAME/SOME_NUMBER/SPI_DEVICE_NAME". Can anyone explain it for me?

Thanks in advance!

Hetty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPI is *strictly* a command- and stream-oriented protocol. Linux does not have any facility for accessing the data available via it in a random manner. Or even in a sequential manner, since it does not have any drivers for SPI devices; all operations must be performed by user software.

Comment: I did find the driver in /drivers/spi. What is that?

Comment: That's the driver for the SPI *interface*.

Comment: OK. My purpose is to read and write the registers in an external FPGA through SPI interface. For this simple purpose, do I have to write a driver? I thought I could open the file through /sys/bus/spi/devices/... and mmap. I have done the same thing for PCIe interface (mmap /sys/bus/pci/devices/...) to read and write registers in FPGA - it worked.

Comment: PCIe registers are block-oriented. SPI is stream-oriented. You wouldn't try to mmap stdin or stdout, would you?

Comment: OK. So do I need to write a kernel driver or user space driver? I am a beginner of linux driver so would like to select a simple way to begin. If user space driver can work, should I use ioctl to serve the read/write need?

Comment: It's SPI. You write a byte, and then you read a byte. You keep doing that until you're done.

Comment: What system call/file operations do I need? Read() and write()?

Comment: Yes. One byte at a time.

Comment: Ok. Take read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count) as an example. To get a file descriptor, I still need to open a file, do I? what file should I open? The "/sys/bus/spi/devices/DEVICE_NAME"?

Comment: Thank you for the info. My understanding is that when the FPGA is connected through the SPI bus, the linux kernel will recognize it because kernel has built-in SPI driver. Is this correct? Will the device node be automatically created? Or I should manually mknod by checking the major number in /proc/devices?

Comment: Linux has a driver for the SPI interface. It knows nothing of any SPI slave devices. It should create the spidev device node. You will need to frob this device in order to communicate with any slave(s).

Comment: When you said "It should create the spidev device node." - is this done automatically when device is physically connected via SPI bus? Or I should do something to make it happen?

Comment: It happens when the SPI interface is detected. **There is no driver for SPI slaves.**

Comment: So SPI interface can be detected automatically. It seems I don't need to write a driver to just read and write the registers through SPI - the read() and write() system call suffice.

Comment: Any driver you would write would just be an abstraction of the basic SPI operations.

Comment: Really appreciated. So I will just open dev/spidev and read() and write(). Correct?

Comment: You also need to assert and deassert the slave select line as required.

Comment: The read()/write() can only read/write a chunk of data from the beginning of the file (fd=open(/dev/spidevB.C). For example, to write 10 FPGA registers(0x0 - 0x9, register width 1 byte), I use write(fd, buf, 10). But is there any efficient way of reading/writing any one register (e.g., 0x5) without reading/writing other registers as a bundle. What function call can work with spi device to serve the purpose?

Comment: Have you looked at the datasheet yet?

Comment: The datasheet for the SPI slave.